# Self execute and call a function in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I would like to have a function, which would be accessible to call it by other functions and should self execute when declared.

Like:

```
function some(var_one, var_two)
{
    // do something
}(var_one, var_two); // declare and execute (doesn't work)

function add_pair()
{
    // do something
    some(James, Amber);
}
```

What is a proper syntax to do this?

Comment: Can't you just call the function right after declaring it? As in, `some(thing1, thing2);`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - Assuming the pair of parentheses after the function declaration are intended to invoke the function, the syntax is not fine. Those parentheses will do nothing at all, since you can't invoke a declaration.

Comment: @JamesAllardice yes, you're correct, OP needs parentesis around the function declaration.

Comment: @James Allardice it's too trivial

Comment: @Rory McCrossan it would become an anonymous function with no ability to call it outside.

Comment: @James - So what is the actual reason for wanting to do this? Just because it seems pointless to have a separate invocation after the declaration, or did you have some other reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot invoke a function declaration. The pair of parentheses following the declaration will do nothing at all. You could do something like this:

```
var some;
(some = function (var_one, var_two) {
    console.log(var_one, var_two);
})("a", "b");

​some("b", "c");​​​​
```

The above example will log "a, b", followed by "b, c". But that looks a bit messy. You could just stick with what you have and call the function like normal:

```
function some(var_one, var_two) {
    console.log(var_one, var_two);
}
some("a", "b");
```

---

**Update**

Note that by changing the function declaration to an expression (which is what happens in my first example above) you remove the ability to call the function *before* it appears to be declared in the source, since declarations are hoisted to the top of the scope in which they appear, and assignments happen in place. With a function declaration, the following example works perfectly:

```
some("a", "b"); // Call it before it appears to be declared
function some(var_one, var_two) {
    console.log(var_one, var_two);
}
```

I really can't see any reason why you would need to combine the declaration and invocation into one.

Comment: nice example, but "var some" is one more line, like a usual function call.

Comment: @James - If you care that much about the extra line, just remove it and have `some` leak to the global scope! Other than that, I don't think you're going to shorten it.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't declare and execute the same time (unless in IE, creating two different functions). Have a look at http://kangax.github.com/nfe/

If your function has no return value, you could exploit that and let the function return itself, making it an immediately-executed-named-function-expression which is assigned to a variable:

```
var someGlobal = (function some(args) {
    // do something
    return some;
})(now_args);

// then
someGlobal(James, Amber);
```

Better use a declaration *and* an invocation, to make things clearer.

Comment: If you have to return `some` itself then the function won't be able to return whatever it's actually intended to return (if it is intended to return something). So "better use a declaration and an invocation" is probably a better suggestion.

Comment: Yes, I already wrote "if the function had no return value". Your assigned-and-executed function expression looks much better :-)

Comment: "undefined is not a function"

Comment: @Bergi - I wouldn't say "better", it's a mess :) I can see no reason you would ever *need* to do this over a simple declaration followed by a simple invocation. Sorry, didn't notice that you had already mentioned the return value part.

Comment: @James: Huh? No call to something undefined. [Worksforme](http://jsfiddle.net/Vw3jG/)

Comment: "undefined" is "someGlobal(...)" in this case

Comment: What browser are you using when visiting [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vw3jG/1/)? `someGlobal` is only undefined if the function didn't return itself, so either you missed `return some` or the name the function expression